# Masterpage + Iframe functionality?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, iframe, master-pages

We implemented masterpages replacing iframes in order to have a clearer way to design. The problem is that in exchange we lost the iframes benefit of partial rendering when redirecting between pages...

We use update panels(ajax .net) in both designs so the only problem remains in redirections...

Comment: @ase69s you search how to redirect from inside an iframe ?

Comment: Nop, i want the combined benefits of using iframes and masterpages: 
-Iframes:  
Loading the content pages in the iframe the menus and headers of the page arent rerendered in the client browser.  

-MasterPages:  
Having the content pages under the master page permits us to view the resulting content page (menus, headers and content) in the visual studio design view, optimizing the visual designing process of the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems nobody knows :S, i imagine that nowadays it would be done with some HTML5 (black)magic